# Heroku Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python==3.6.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I am trying to deploy python 3 django my web app using Heroku and am getting the following issue when trying to `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 251, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (128/128), done.
Writing objects: 100% (251/251), 408.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 251 (delta 122), reused 241 (delta 117)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.13
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Python==3.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e93a318fd7d055dbf50a8f1974aa0537/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python==3.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e93a318fd7d055dbf50a8f1974aa0537/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for Python==3.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_e93a318fd7d055dbf50a8f1974aa0537/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to willrholmes-organiser.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/willrholmes-organiser.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

My requirements.txt, runtime.txt and Procfile look as follows:

Requirements:

```
aadict==0.2.3
appdirs==1.4.2
arrow==0.10.0
asset==0.6.12
binaryornot==0.4.3
chardet==3.0.2
click==6.7
cookiecutter==1.5.1
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.10.6
django-bootstrap-datepicker==1.2.2
docker==2.2.1
docker-pycreds==0.2.1
future==0.16.0
globre==0.1.5
gunicorn==19.7.1
Jinja2==2.9.6
jinja2-time==0.2.0
lessc==0.1.2
MarkupSafe==1.0
packaging==16.8
poyo==0.4.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
pyparsing==2.1.10
python-dateutil==2.6.0
requests==2.13.0
selenium==3.0.2
six==1.10.0
websocket-client==0.40.0
whichcraft==0.4.1
```

runtime.txt:

```
python-3.6.1
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn organiser.wsgi --log-file -
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your `runtime.txt` file in the root of your repository?

Comment: Yeah it is. I have no idea what the problem was but fixed it by making a new directory, running `git init` and then pulling the whole app to the new directory. Just seemed to work. Thanks for your help though!